# rails adding children to user account

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I have a website that allows people to create accounts and to register for tournaments.  I want the users to be able to add their minor children to their account.  The children will not have access to the site.  The parent woulc login and find the tournament and register the children on there account in the tournament.  I got some advice from another post. So I'll shware what I have here.

From, the user's account on the users/show page I have the link:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("layout/profile_add_family.gif", class: "profile_pic", width: "140px").html_safe, new_user_child_path(@user)) %>
```

When I click on the link it tekes me to localhost:3000/users/1/children/new and I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `children' for 1:Integer):

app/controllers/children_controller.rb:6:in `new'
```

My routes are:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations', omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
  root 'pages#index'
  resources :events, param: :tourn_url
  get 'features', to: 'pages#features'
  get 'pricing', to: 'pages#pricing'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  get 'contact', to: 'pages#contact'
  get 'privacy', to: 'pages#privacy'
  get 'terms', to: 'pages#terms'
  get 'remove', to: 'pages#remove'
  delete 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users, param: :username do 
    resources :children
  end
```

My children_controller:

```
class ChildrenController < ApplicationController
  before_action :user
  before_action :child, only: %i[create]

  def new
    @child = @user.children.new
  end

  def create
    byebug
    if @child.save
      flash[:success] = 'Child was successfully created.'
      redirect_to locations_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = @child.errors.full_messages.join('<br />').html_safe
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user 
    @user = current_user.id
  end

  def child
    @child = user.children.new(child_params)
  end

  def child_params
    params.require(:child).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :dob, :gender, :legan_guardian)
  end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `user` method is defining `@user` as `current_user.id`.

You probably just want this to be `current_user`.

Comment: That's what I had originanally.  I've tried several things but I chenced it to current_user and still get the error: `NoMethodError (undefined method `children' for #<User:0x000000000c408808>):`

Comment: That's a different error entirely. The first one is `undefined method children' for 1:Integer):`, meaning `@user` came out as the number 1. Now the error is `undefined method children' for #<User:0x000000000c408808>`, meaning your user class doesn't have the `children` method. So your association isn't set up properly. Post your User model.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I hadn't added has_many :children.  So now I'm not getting the error but I now I get the message there is no template for the page..  I have users/children/new.html.erb but should it be somewhere else?  The route says: `/users/:user_username/children/new`

Comment: I don't use nested routes like this much, but maybe try just putting it in `views/children/new.html.erb`. Also don't forget to mark the answer as correct above.

Comment: That did it.  The url says users/judo2000/children/new but when I moved the children folder out of users into views it worked.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Happy to help. I was in your spot 10 years ago ;) Some generous folks helped me out just like this and I feel good giving back. Hopefully you will too when it's your time :)

Comment: If I ever learn this stuff I will definitely be happy to help others!  Thanks again!